# How can I access loaded scripts in index.html via ng-included templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm a AngularJS-Beginner and i've just started using ng-include to better structure my html blocks.

I'm using jquery.scrollTo.js to add a button to scroll to the top. However i've noticed that if I place the button inside tpl-footer.html and load it via ng-inlcude while having jquery.scrollTo loaded in index.html, it won't work. 
I either have to place the button inside index.html or load jquery.scrollTo.js inside tpl-footer.html.

My question: How can I access loaded scripts in index.html via ng-included templates?

Cheers!

Comment: Scripts in templates are ignored. Use directives to initialize jQuery plugins so you are assured elements exist when activated.

Comment: You dont need to use ng-include, newer angularjs has that built in just make sure you write it into your module. and then reference it in whatever controller/directive you need it in.

Comment: @charlietfl is right. I have the same problem ı just call init function in controller and problem is solved .

Comment: @esatilmis except controller can fire before template is loaded, one of the reasons not to use dom code in controllers

Comment: @charlietfl   `    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        _toggle();
    });`  i use like this is it a problem ?

Comment: @esatilmis document was ready a long time ago. angular doesn't bootstrap until then

Comment: @charlietfl  it is good to learn thank you